# Uppercase accented characters displayed as “?”

Tags: java, utf-8, character, decoding, latin1

I got a string value from a db table with latin1 as collation. Though, he text contains UTF-8 characters.

So I did this in my web server logic (Java) to resolve weird characters :

```
 new String(latin1.getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Everything is fine now but uppercase accented characters (ex: À) are still displayed as '?'. Only uppercase one are still in problem (ex: à is resolved now and is displaying correctly).

Is there a way to resolve uppercase accented characters as well?

Comment: Where are you displaying the string? Console, log file? Is it possible to provide a full example of a string?

Comment: ctrl+shift+d on the variable directly in Eclipse debug mode.

Comment: I tried your code in test I wrote. I read the string from a text file with ISO encoding and then transforming it and it works fine for both characters. Of course it's not 100% accurate but still... Could you try printing the variable in the console instead of using the debugger?

Comment: I got the same result. Here is a part of the encoded string from the DB : Ã–rphÃ«Ã¼m if you want to give it a try.

Comment: I always get : �?rphëüm as the result.

Comment: Try this `new String(latin1.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);`

Comment: Same result. But I think I came up with a solution.

Comment: @NinjaFisherman could you please share you solution , i am also facing same issue in java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it may not be the best solution, but it surely worked for me and fulfill our needs.

The problem seems to be related with the getBytes method vs mapping encoding. We simply mapped our column with a byte[] to avoid any conversion on WebServer/Hibernate side.

This way we can call new String(myByteArray, StandardCharsets.UTF-8) and now the output is good!